# JSF/RichFaces: conditional text styling

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a string which can be yes or no, instantiated in an object in a Java backing bean.  I can't seem to find the best way to conditionally style the text red or green dependent on whether the JSF gets yes or no from the bean respectively.  I'm using richfaces, but should I be using `<c:if>` tags?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

(in order of preference):

- `style="color: #{yourVar == 'yes' ? 'green' : 'red'};"`
- make two `<h:outputText>` components with different styles, each with a different `rendered` attribute (one `#{yourVar == 'yes'}` and the other `#{yourVar == 'no'}`)
- define a (jstl/facelets/jsf 2.0) function that takes the var as argument and returns a style/class - `styleClass="#{my:getStyleClass(yourVar)}"`

Comment: IMHO, better is a method that returns the class name or empty string so:
<input type=text class="#{bean.className}" />

Comment: @Luke, IMHO that's only more clutter in the bean. It doesn't need to know anything about the view-specific stuff. An EL ternary condition in `style` or `styleClass` (option 1 by Bozho) makes perfectly sense here.